# How to make a sidebar and a textInput object in one row

Tags: user-interface, shiny

The problem is I want to put a `helpText` object at the right of a `sidebarPanel` object. Here is my code:

```
    ui <- (fluidPage(
# Application title
fluidRow(
  column(12,
  sidebarPanel(
  titlePanel("Visualization"),
  actionButton("goButton", "Go"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
  actionButton("pause", "Pause"),
  actionButton("resume", "Resume"),
  textInput("initial", "Initial Value", value = "c(-5, 5, 5)")  ,
  textInput("targ", "Target", value = "c(0, 0, 0)"),
  textInput("func", "Objective Function", value = "x1 ^ 2 + exp(x2 ^ 2) + 5 + x3 ^ 2")
)),
  column(12,helpText('XXX'))
)
))
```

However, the helpText is just below the sidebarPanel. How can I fix this and make helpText object at the right blank area.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `mainPanel` to the first column and put there `helpText`. In the example below I set the width of the column to 8 out of max 12.

This `mainPanel` is 8/12 of the column of the width 8 and `sidebarPanel` is of width 4/12 of the same column.

There is still a place for another column with maximal width of 4 and I placed there another `helpText`.

This answer may be a little bit off topic but the question was vage as well :)

---

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(8, # column width goes from 1 to 12 where 12 is the whole screen

           sidebarPanel( # default 4 / 12 ... in this case 3/4 of 8
             titlePanel("Visualization"),
             actionButton("goButton", "Go"),
             actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
             actionButton("pause", "Pause"),
             actionButton("resume", "Resume"),
             textInput("initial", "Initial Value", value = "c(-5, 5, 5)")  ,
             textInput("targ", "Target", value = "c(0, 0, 0)"),
             textInput("func", "Objective Function", value = "x1 ^ 2 + exp(x2 ^ 2) + 5 + x3 ^ 2")
           ),
           mainPanel( # 8 /12 ... so 3/4 of 8
             helpText('XXX'),
             helpText("width of the mainPanel within the first column"),
             hr()
           )
    ),
    column(4, 
           br(),
           helpText('width of the second column'),
           hr()
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There are a lot of other possible answers to your question since one can create almost an arbitrary layout with the grid system :) http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html